# URI and a resource in xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources, uri, imagesource

I have a class that acts as a view model for a view. That class has a public member of type ImageSource. Now what I need is to change the property type to uri (or string).
But the problem is I can't find a way to access a single resource from a resource dicionary with an URI.

e.g. at the moment I'm doing sth like this:

```csharp
VectorResourcesDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
Uri uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/assembly;component/IconResources.xaml", UriKind.Absolute);
VectorResourcesDictionary.Source = uri;
object rawResource = VectorResourcesDictionary["VectorIcon.LeftArrowIcon"];
return pickerSymbol = rawResource as ImageSource;
```

Now how can I get a similar result using a URI instead of an ImageSource?

Comment: I thing you do MVVM in a wrong way. Images, Styles, etc. that relate to UI should belong to View not ViewModel. I suggest you move it to the view (xaml file.)

Comment: Yes, I know it wrong, that's why I have to change the ImageSource (ui element) to a simple string or URI. The question is how to get a simple resource defined in xaml with an URI ...

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, just change the property type from ImageSource to Uri:

```csharp
public Uri PickerSymbol // i just guess the property name
{
    get
    {
        // get resource as string instead of ImageSource
        ...
        string uri = rawResource as string
        return new Uri(uri);
    }
}
```

In your view keep the binding to the PickerSymbol property, the Uri will automatically be converted to ImageSource.

```
<Image Source="{Binding PickerSymbol}" />
```